# User Interface Automation of Adams/Postprocessor

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, automation

I would like to automate a very long and repetitive set of tasks in Adams/Postprocessor (2012). I have googled for ways to automate the setup of the various view panes for the graphs and animations I want to display. However, there seems to be no native support for scripting, macro keys, templates, or anything else like that.

The tasks I am performing involve text input from the keyboard, mouse pointing, and mouse clicking. Is there anyway I can automate such tasks. For example, is there external software that records all mouse and keyboard input and can then repeat the exact order of keyboard inputs, and mouse inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I often use these popular macro recorder tools for similar tasks:

- [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/) (classic, via coordinates etc)
- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) (via screenshots and image recognition)

You will need to test and see which approach works better (= easier to create, more stable macros) for your app.